# SqlAlchemy 1.4 session event 'after_flush" don't triggered

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

there.
I'm trying to catch the session even `"after flush"`. But I can't. I can catch event `"after_commit"` or `"before_commit"` and it works fine. In debugger i see registered event handlers. But triggered only `"after_commit"` or `"before_commit"`

In general, I want to get event. Get model data (inserted, updates) and send it to kafka

I can't imagine why this happens

Method witch store data to db

```py
....
@classmethod
    def bulk_create(
        cls,
        *,
        offer: mdl.Offer,
        organization_id: int,
        count: int,
        payment_id: Optional[str] = None,
        payment_dt: Optional[datetime.datetime] = None,
        create_method: Optional[str] = None,
        commit: bool = False,
        is_transferred: bool = False,
        is_discount: bool = True,
        order_id: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> List[mdl.Subscription]:
        """ Множественное создание подписок и продуктов к ним """
        subscriptions = [
            mdl.Subscription(
                offer_id=offer.id,
                duration=offer.duration,
                payment_id=payment_id,
                payment_dt=payment_dt,
                organization_id=organization_id,
                status=constants.SubscriptionStatus.READY,
                create_method=create_method,
                is_transferred=is_transferred,
                is_discount=is_discount,
                order_id=order_id,
            )
            for _ in range(count)
        ]

        mdl.db.session.bulk_save_objects(subscriptions, return_defaults=True)
        mdl.db.session.flush()

        if commit:
            mdl.db.session.commit()

        return subscriptions
```

**UPD:** If I use

```py
        # mdl.db.session.bulk_save_objects(subscriptions, return_defaults=True)
        mdl.db.session.add(subscriptions[0])
        mdl.db.session.add(subscriptions[1])
        mdl.db.session.flush()
```

Events `after flush` and `before_flush` are work

[image]